# Knockout event binding with condition

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I want to bind some events to an element , using the knockout "event" binding
But I want all of the listed events to be bound only with a specific case.

The viewmodel:

```
function vm(){
var self = this;
self.isEditMode = ko.observable(false);//can be changed to true
self.events = ko.observable({
    down: function () {
        console.log("down")
    },
    up: function () {
        console.log("up")
    },
    hover: function () {
        console.log("hover")
    }
});
```

}

and the Html:

```
    <div style="border:1px solid red;width:50px;height:50px"
         data-bind="event:{mousedown:events().down,mouseup:events().up,mouseover:events().hover}:null"></div>
    <button data-bind="click:function(){isEditMode(!isEditMode())}">change </button>
```

I tried:

```
 <div data-bind="event:isEditMode()?{mousedown:events().down,mouseup:events().up,mouseover:events().hover}:null"></div>
```

But it did not work for me.

I think the best way to do it is by using custom bindingHandlers, but I dont know how.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: first of all Did it work without isEditMode() condition ?

Comment: I just checked your code and its working when isEditMode is false. What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: yes , it works without isEditMode() condition. It even works with isEditMode() condition , when it sets to true , but if sets to false (by clicking on the button i added recently to the above) - I get a ko error.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting then?

Comment: It occures when the mouse is hover the div

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseover' of null , but note that the main problem is that when isEditMode sets to false as default , it will not rebind after chang to true

Comment: <div style="border:1px solid red;width:50px;height:50px"
        data-bind="event: {mousedown: isEditMode()? events().down :null,
                           mouseup: isEditMode()? events().up:null, mouseover:isEditMode()? events().hover:null }"  >
          
</div>  Changing the binding to this, its working

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the the binding by moving some logic into the view model

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:50px;height:50px"
     data-bind="event: {
        mousedown: down, 
        mouseup:up, 
        mouseover:hover }" > </div>
```

and view model like this

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;
    this.isEditMode = ko.observable(true);
    down = function() {
        if(this.isEditMode())
        {
            console.log("down")
        }
    };
    up = function() {
       if(this.isEditMode())
        {
            console.log("up")
        }
    };
    hover = function() {
        if(this.isEditMode())
        {
            console.log("hover")
        }
    };
}

var viewModel = new vm();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: That was my first step  , but I prefer to prevent a reusable code. I want to support also more events that will be there in the future , to force them have that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to place the condition in the markup itself as two separate blocks using an "if" binding to determine which ones gets shown and bound.

```js
function vm() {
  var self = this;
  self.isEditMode = ko.observable(false); //can be changed to true
  self.events = ko.observable({
    down: function() {
      console.log("down");
    },
    up: function() {
      console.log("up");
    },
    hover: function() {
      console.log("hover");
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!--ko if: isEditMode()-->
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:50px;height:50px" data-bind="event:{
            mousedown:events().down,
            mouseup:events().up,
            mouseover:events().hover
        }">
  Edit Mode
</div>
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko if: !isEditMode()-->
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:50px;height:50px">
  Read Only
</div>
<!--/ko-->


<button data-bind="click:function(){isEditMode(!isEditMode())}">change </button>
```